# Retrieve values from sql

Tags: python, pandas

i'm new to python and trying to retrieve data from a sql database and get the values of columns? so far i've got the data out from the sql with below statement, but not sure how to get the values. i'm using Panda

```
data = C.readData('SELECT AVG(CPU_AVG) as CPU_AVG, MAX(CPU_MAX) as CPU_MAX FROM EXA_STATISTICS.EXA_SQL_HOURLY WHERE INTERVAL_START = ' + todayString)
```

when i print this i get

```
     CPU_AVG  CPU_MAX
0  21.666667     24.5
```

how do i get the values of CPU_AVG and CPU_MAX

Comment: Hi, haven't you already got them displayed?

Comment: yes but how do i access the values

Comment: if you are using pandas, `df['CPU_AVG']` will give you its correspond value

Comment: this return `0    21.666667
Name: CPU_AVG, dtype: float64`. what i want to get is 21.666667

Comment: And that is the correct result, but just as a numpy `float64` value...

Comment: @PeterPik check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> df['CPU_AVG'].values[0]
21.666667
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use pymysql package instead. It works as follows:

```
db = pymysql.connect(host=hostname, port=yourPort, user=userName, passwd=password, db=databaseName)

cur = db.cursor()
```

Then you can query the database as follows:

```
cur.execute("SELECT AVG(CPU_AVG) as CPU_AVG, MAX(CPU_MAX) as CPU_MAX FROM EXA_STATISTICS.EXA_SQL_HOURLY WHERE INTERVAL_START = " + todayString)
```

and to fetch the resulting data, do:

```
data = cur.fetchall()
```

You will end up with a tuple containing your parameters values.

Comment: can't i'm using exasol SDK, which use Panda

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Series.item`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.item.html):

```
print (df['CPU_AVG'].item())
21.666667
```

Another solutions with [`iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iat.html) or [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iloc.html) for selecting by position:

```
print (df['CPU_AVG'].iat[0])
21.666667

print (df['CPU_AVG'].iloc[0])
21.666667
```